Why is blender crashing with this code line: bpy.ops.gpencil.convert(type='CURVE', use_timing_data=context.scene.transfer_gp_timing_data_toggle)
I selected a grease pencil scribble that wasn't too complex, and the convert tab grease pencil to mesh works very fast on my computer. Blender crashes when executing this line:
curve_obj = bpy.ops.gpencil.convert(type='CURVE', use_timing_data=context.scene.transfer_gp_timing_data_toggle)
In blender python API code:
import bpy

class GreasePencilDisplayAsMeshPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
  bl_label = "Grease Pencil Display As Mesh"
  bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_GPENCIL_DAM"
  bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
  bl_region_type = 'UI'
  bl_category = "Display GP As Mesh"
   
  def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    obj = context.object
    #op = layout.operator("object.greasepencil_to_curve")
    #op.extrude_threshold = context.scene.gp_converter_threshold
    #op.material_index = context.scene.gp_converter_material_index
    #layout.prop(context.scene, "gp_converter_active")
   
    #display toggle
    row = layout.row()
    row.prop(context.scene, "grease_pencil_display_as_mesh_toggle", expand=False)
     
    if context.scene.grease_pencil_display_as_mesh_toggle==True:
      #transfer grease pencil timing data toggle
      row = layout.row()
      row.prop(context.scene, "transfer_gp_timing_data_toggle", expand=False)
       
      #plane extrusion
      row = layout.row()
      row.prop(context.scene, "gp_converter_threshold", expand=False)
       
      # Get all materials for material loader
      materials = bpy.data.materials
       
      #material loader
      row = layout.row()
      row.prop(context.scene, "gp_converter_material", text="Materials", expand=False)

# Function to update the extrusion when slider is changed
def update_extrusion(context):

  # Extrude the curve
  bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
  bpy.ops.curve.extrude(move_z=self.extrude_threshold)
  bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

  """
  # Assign material
  if scene.gp_converter_material: # Check if a material is selected
    curve_obj['data'].materials[0] = bpy.data.materials.get(scene.gp_converter_material)
  """

  return {'FINISHED'}

def update_curve(self, context):
  if context.scene.grease_pencil_display_as_mesh_toggle==True:
     # Get the active grease pencil object
    gp_obj = context.active_object
    if gp_obj is None or gp_obj.type != 'GPENCIL':
      self.report({'ERROR'}, 'Select a Grease Pencil object')
      return {'CANCELLED'}

    # Store the grease pencil's visibility state
    gp_obj_visibility = gp_obj.hide_viewport 

    # Convert to curve
    curve_obj = bpy.ops.gpencil.convert(type='CURVE', use_timing_data=context.scene.transfer_gp_timing_data_toggle)

    # Hide the grease pencil
    gp_obj.hide_viewport = True
    #bpy.ops.object.greasepencil_to_curve()
     
  else:
    # Search for existing curves created by the operator
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
      if obj.get('gp_converter_origin'): 
        bpy.data.objects.remove(obj, do_unlink=True)

    # Unhide the original grease pencil object 
    gp_objs = [obj for obj in bpy.data.objects if obj.get('gp_converter_origin')]
    if gp_objs:
      gp_objs[0].hide_viewport = gp_objs[0]['gp_converter_visibility'] 
       
def get_material_items(self, context):
  """
  This function generates a list of (identifier, name, description) tuples
  for all materials in the Blender scene, suitable for an EnumProperty.
  """
  items = [('NONE', 'None', 'No material assigned')]
  for mat in bpy.data.materials:
    items.append((mat.name, mat.name, ""))

  return items

def update_materials(self, context):
  items = self.get_material_items(context) # Regenerate items
  context.scene.gp_converter_material.items = items

def register():
  bpy.ops.wm.console_toggle()
  bpy.utils.register_class(GreasePencilDisplayAsMeshPanel)
  bpy.types.Scene.grease_pencil_display_as_mesh_toggle = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
  name="gp display as mesh toggle",
  description="Display the grease pencil as a mesh with this checkbox checked.",
  default=False,
  update=lambda self, context: update_curve(context) # Call update_extrusion when the button changes
)
  bpy.types.Scene.transfer_gp_timing_data_toggle = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
  name="gp transfer timing data toggle",
  description="Transfer the gp timing data with this checkbox checked.",
  default=True
)
  bpy.types.Scene.gp_converter_threshold = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
  name="extrude threshold",
  description="Change the size of the planes created by extrusion.",
  default=0.01,
  min=0.0,
  #update=lambda self, context: update_extrusion(context) # Call update_extrusion when the slider changes 
)
  bpy.types.Scene.gp_converter_material = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
  name="materials",
  description="The material to assign to the curve.",
  items=get_material_items,
  update=update_materials
)
  #bpy.types.Scene.gp_converter_active = bpy.props.BoolProperty(update=update_curve)

def unregister():
  bpy.utils.unregister_class(GreasePencilDisplayAsMeshPanel)
  del bpy.types.Scene.grease_pencil_display_as_mesh_toggle
  del bpy.types.Scene.transfer_gp_timing_data_toggle
  del bpy.types.Scene.gp_converter_threshold
  del bpy.types.Scene.gp_converter_material

if __name__ == "__main__":
  register()


If blender is crashing and it can be reproduced every time, you should report this as a bug (Help::Report_Bug).  No one from the development team hangs out on this site.  Be sure to include your crash.txt file from AppData/Local/Temp.
